# How to integrate JWPlayer with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn, jwplayer

I am looking for a way to integrate a JWPlayer with React, I know this is possible using their cloud hosted player on a static server-rendered language, but im finding it nearly impossible to make this happen elsewhere. I've been looking around the forums as well and the option that most people used previously which was `react-jw-player` doesnt look like its being supported anymore you cant install the package via `npm` and JWPlayer doesnt provide any documentation on how to work with their player in different frameworks.

so im wondering if there is a way to implement their cloud player from their cdn that they give you, for example, in their documentation
you would use a script tag to load the .js with an https that they provide you for the player, and then you can initialize a player from there.
looks like this:

```
***this is in the header***
<script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/.../.."></script>
**************************
<div id="myElement"></div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({ 
        "playlist": [{
           "file": "videourl"
            }]
        });
    </script>
```

I'd like to think that this is somewhat possible to do in react as well, but simply adding the `cdn` to the header in the index.js file, and then trying to instantiate a player object doesnt work, (if only it were that simple right?)

so im reaching out to the broader community in hopes someone might have a lead for me on how to use JWPlayer in React

Comment: Hey Austin, did you managed to integrate jwplayer in React JS application?

Comment: @SarfarazAhmed i did actually find a way to make the JWPlayer CDN work inside of the React Application, however its been months since i worked on it that i dont have the implementation, i instead went with an implementation of VideoJS instead, as it was easier to integrate into the application itself.